# Computing DeRham Cohomology of $H^{1}(\Bbb{R})$ and $H^{1}(S^{1})$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

How do I compute the DeRham Cohomology of $H^{1}(\Bbb{R})$ and $H^{1}(S^{1})$ ?

Like for $H^{1}(\Bbb{R})$,

$H^{1}(\Bbb{R}) = \frac{Z^{1}(\Bbb{R})}{B^{1}(\Bbb{R})}$,
But what will be $Z^{1}(\Bbb{R})$ ? , where $Z^{1}(\Bbb{R}) = \{$ 1 - forms which are closed like $M dx = 0 \}$.

and

$B^{1}(\Bbb{R})= \{$ 1 -forms which are exact $\}$.

After this I am unable to proceed?

Comment: The way you may want to approach this is by using some well known properties of (co)homology. E.g. $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible hence the cohomology is trivial. For $S^1$ see Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms. Most (co)homology theories obey them and $H(S^1)$ can be easily calculated from them.

Comment: Cannot I compute it  using the basic definitions as above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) By the fundamental theorem of calculus $B^1(\mathbb{R})=Z^1(\mathbb{R})=\Omega^1(\mathbb{R})$, hence $H^1(\mathbb{R})=0.$

(2) Show that $\int\colon Z^1(S^1)=\Omega^1(S^1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has $B^1(S^1)$ as kernel, then use the first isomorphism theorem (in linear algebra) to compute $H^1(S^1)\cong\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Then is it true that all $1$ forms on $\Bbb{R}$ are both exact and closed? as you have written $B^{1}(\Bbb{R}) = Z^{1}(\Bbb{R})$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is true.